# php echo floor error line 66

Tags: php, html

I am trying to echo the below in a new way but I get an error

**old code**

```
echo floor ($row ['avprice']);
```

**New code , line 66**

```
echo floor '<h5> '.($row ['avprice']).'</h5>';
```

**Error**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting ',' or ';' in
>   C:\wamp\www\boot\details1.php on line 66

I have tried changing the " and ' ' but no joy whatever I try. I m basically just trying to round the price down or just remove everything after the decimal place , so "no" decimal places.

Thanks

Comment: `echo '<h5>'. floor ($row ['avprice']).'</h5>';`

Comment: floor($number) -> $number must be numeric!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure you didn't tried this:-

```
echo '<h5>'. floor($row ['avprice']) .'</h5>';
```

You can do like below (what you asked in comment):-

```
echo '£<h5>'. floor($row ['avprice']) .'</h5>';
```

Or

```
echo '<h5>£'. floor($row ['avprice']) .'</h5>';
```

Comment: Also I tried to echo a £ before the price , but I cant get it on the same line. Any ideas ?

Comment: `echo '<h5>£'. floor($row ['avprice']) .'</h5>';`, like that? @Bill